# SQL Server Report Builder - Only Display Running Total

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, report, reporting

I have a table in Report Builder that holds how many customers were served in a specific Program by specific Branch.

Branch -> Program -> Customers Served

I keep a running total of this but that is all that I need to be displayed, not the total for every record. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What total do you want to see and what total do you not want to see?

Comment: How looks your dataset? What field you want to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear what is required - have you looked at the `RunningValue` function, i.e. something like?

```
=RunningValue(Fields!CustomersServed.Value, Sum, Nothing)
```

Any more information such as an example dataset and what results you'd like to see would be most helpful.